# Purpose of SpriteKit sks files

Tags: objective-c, macos, sprite-kit

I've watched the WWDC 2014 session (#608 "Best practices for building sprite kit games") a couple of times and **I just want to clarify the purpose behind using .sks files**. Am I supposed to put separate assets into each .sks file? Here's a little bit of background into what I'm doing. I'm creating a Mac app that will text piano students to play chords using a MIDI keyboard. Chords will appear on the screen and they'll play them one by one and get a score. Here's a mockup of what the app may look like. Side note: for those that may know music, we're using the numeric version of chords instead of explicit names like Cm, etc.

Would I have a separate .sks file for each element of the UI. For instance, one for the green timer bar, one for the piano keys, etc. The example that they use in the video is a pretty simple one. I am subclassing SKSpriteNode for the timer and on-screen piano so how would I handle the resources for those. They are not static objects and they will change either over time (timer) or due to user input (keyboard)

I really want to organize my project using best practices. Please help. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sks files are serialized SKScene objects. The intent is to provide something like interface builder for constructing SKScene scenes visually. The common use case is to layout complex backgrounds or levels and define starting positions. You would only have one file per scene in many cases. However you can use the sks files to organize and serialize conceptual components of a scene, as demonstrated in versions of the Apple Adventure sample code released since the sks format and scene editor were introduced with Xcode 6

In the screenshot above, you could organize the project into sections that are fairly generic and reusable, like the keyboard for one file and the hud atop the scene for another file. However, you could put them all in one file, then duplicate the file for variations on a theme.

Comment: you could have separate files for reusable elements like a HUD for each player. This is the case in apple's example adventure game.

Comment: ah I didn't realize that! Updated. I haven't seen that example since before the sks files were introduced. Use cases I saw were simpler and the scene editor was so buggy last time I used it.

Comment: Also, to tag on to what Okapi said, Apple seemed to use one for the actual scene (static objects) and a separate one for related items. This is why I'm asking because it seems that there are different ways that .sks files are being used.

Comment: The thing is they're all objects in a scene. It's really a lot like nibs/xibs but for sprite kit. It lets you do a lot of configuration and design visually. You can even use them as placeholders that you replace at load time.

Comment: You mentioned in your edit above that I could use the HUD in one file. I currently have those elements (the numeric timer and score as a bunch of SKLabelNodes). How would that work?

Comment: Keep in mind SKScene is an SKEffectNode and that's an SKNode. You just load it and pick up the bits you want by name.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that out as I've been putting the project together. For the on-screen piano, it's composed of two different sprites (the white key and the black key). Is this a job for the .sks file or should this be put together using some other method?

Comment: Seems like a reasonable use case. Whatever is manageable for developing and maintaining. The immediate trade off is diffs of sks files will be a lot less readable just like nib/xib files when working with version control. The other trade off is always where do you put configuration stuff? The best bet is to document things for yourself for months later when you come back to it. A readme file or comments in a good line of code will do wonders later.